# Installing Project Server 2010 on upgraded SharePoint 2010 Farm

Tags: 2010

Wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of articles / info regarding the following scenario:

I have a MOSS 2007 single server farm that I am going to migrate to new hardware and SharePoint 2010 using Database Attach method.

The client then wants to install Project Server 2010 on this same farm - new installation of Project server, they have not used it before.

So, I guess my main question for now is what order should I do all of this?

I am thinking along the lines of the following:

1. Install SP2010
2. Install Project Server 2010
3. Configure SP2010 with a web app to host the upgraded 2007 MOSS site collection
4. Configure a new web app / site collection for Project server 2010
5. Perform DB attach of MOSS 2007 collection.

Any ideas suggestions will be welcome.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Move and Upgrade your DB's first to 2010, make sure it all works.  Then you can install PS2010.

Be aware that Project extends the schema of the DB's and uninstallation is not supported.